# Stretch the last column in a Webix datatable

Tags: html, css, datagrid, webix

How can the last column in a [Webix datatable](http://webix.com/widget/datatable/) be stretched so it extends from the previous column to the right edge of the screen? I'm trying to achieve the column layout below:

[image]

I've set `autowidth: false` and the container div's width is `100%`, but the result is just blank space after the last column:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps @Aquatic can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**fillspace**](http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.datatable_columns_config.html) property of the column will be the solution. It may have Boolean and numeric values.

There can be more than one fillspace in the datatable; in this case width will be calculated on the base of a proportion defined [by numeric values](http://docs.webix.com/datatable__sizing.html).

```
columns:[
  { id:"rank", header:"Rank"},
  { id:"title", header:"Title", width:250},
  { id:"year", header:"Year"}, 
  { id:"votes", header:"Votes", fillspace:1}
]
```

Please check it in the snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/dd113b85